# Let $\Phi$ be standard Gaussian CDF and $u > 0$. What is good u-bound for $\int_0^1\Phi(u/r - ur)dr$ as a function of $u$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian-integral

Let the function $\Phi(x) := (1/\sqrt{2\pi})\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2}dt$ be the standard Gaussian CDF. For $u > 0$, define $I(u) := \int_0^1 \Phi(u/r-ur)dr$.

> **Question.** What are good upper-bounds for $I(u)$ in terms of $u$ ?

Comment: You could try replacing the normal cdf with the cdf of a stochastically dominating r.v.

Comment: Sure, a CDF such that $\Phi \le F$ and the corresponding integral for $F$ is simpler to control. Do you have a reasonable guess for such a CDF ?

Comment: The standard Gaussian CDF is the integral of the standard Gaussian pdf from $-\infty$ to $x$ not from $0$ to $x$ as you have it.

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good simple upper bound for $u > 1$:

Using integration by parts and then the substitution $w = \frac{u}{r} - ur$, we have
\begin{align}
I(u) &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}w^2} 
(\sqrt{w^2+4u^2} - w)\mathrm{d} w\\
&\le \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}w^2}
\left(2u + \frac{w^2}{4u} - w\right)\mathrm{d} w\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{1}{16u^2}.
\end{align}
The upper bound $I_1(u) = 1 - \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{1}{16u^2}$ is good if $u > 1$.
For example, $\frac{I_1(1)-I(1)}{I(1)} \approx 0.009176113058$,
$\frac{I_1(2)-I(2)}{I(2)} \approx 0.0007002868670$, and $\frac{I_1(10)-I(10)}{I(10)} \approx 0.000001187547307$.

Comment: Great, thanks (upvoted). The condition $u > 1$ is really restrictive. Any insights on the case of small $u$ ?

Comment: @dohmatob I will think about it.

Comment: @dohmatob My upper bound for $u > 0$ is quite complicated (not as simple as the upper bound for $u > 1$).